# XmlHttpRequest returning state 4 too soon

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, xmlhttprequest-states

I'm developing a javascript code to run on an embedded device using the ANT Galio browser.

Ideally, I'd like the code to make a get request to another server. After that get request is made, the page would not allow the user to submit another get request, until a response had been received from the previous get request.

For some reason sometimes I am receiving a readyState of 4 almost instantly. It is as though it is evaluating the previous XmlHttpRequest object and not the new one. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var fail= function (env, resp, stat) {

        alert(resp);
};
var succ= function (env, resp) {
};

var canScan = true;

/* start scan */
function scan (name) {
        if (canScan) {
                //deactivate button
                deactivateScanButtons();
                //let server know
                ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var scanUrl = 'http://19X.1XX.X.XX:8080/scan/' + name
                ajax.open('GET', scanUrl, true);
                ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (ajax.readyState==4) {
                                //allow button to work again
                                activateScanButtons();
                                alert("ready state 4");


                        };
                };

                ajax.send();
//initiate scan
                xrxScanInitiateScan(
                        'http://127.0.0.1',
                        "ftp.xst",
                        false,
                        succ,
                        fail);
        }

}

function deactivateScanButtons () {
//      canScan = false;

        var indicator = document.getElementById('buttons');
        indicator.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
function activateScanButtons () {
//      canScan = true;

        var indicator = document.getElementById('buttons');
        indicator.style.visibility = "visible";

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 suggestions:

1. To avoid any caching on the client side, add a randomly generated number, or the current timestamp to the request querystring.
2. As Yoni said, initiate your `XMLHttpRequest` object with `var` keyword.
3. For each request, save the current timestamp within a global variable. In `onreadystatechange`, call `activateScanButtons` only if the global timestamp matches the corresponding timestamp of that given request. This way, only the latest request will be able to call `activateScanButtons`.

Answer (score 1):

You define the ajax object in `scan` function without the `var` keyword before it. This means that it is a global object, not local. Afterwards, you have a closure - you refer to that variable in the `onreadystate` callback function.

I find it hard to track exactly what's going on there, but I agree with you, as you say in your question, that the callback is not using the ajax object the way you expect. You say it happens sometimes - does it happen when you make two requests almost simultaneously (double-click a button or otherwise trigger the two get requests very fast)?

I suggest that you use the `var` keyword before defining the ajax object. Even better, try using `this` in the callback function instead of referring to the ajax object by name. If it works, you have spared yourself of one closure.